# how can I save the data of a google sheets table with app script in a class?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a class named 'Variables' with all parametres that I want to store the data of the table. Please someone know how to save these content to my variables?

[Table that I want to save data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjMVb.png)

```js
class Variables{
  constructor(image, pantalla, tipo_etiquetado, tipo_llamada, page_name, page_section, page_category, page_subcategory1, event_category, event_action, event_label, product_unit_price){
    this.image = image;
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
    this.tipo_etiquetado = tipo_etiquetado;
    this.tipo_llamada = tipo_llamada;
    this.page_name = page_name;
    this.page_section = page_section;
    this.page_category = page_category;
    this.page_subcategory1 = page_subcategory1;
    this.event_category = event_category;
    this.event_action = event_action;
    this.event_label = event_label;
    this.product_unit_price = product_unit_price;
  }

  get image(){}
  get pantalla(){}
  get tipo_etiquetado(){}
  get tipo_llamada(){}
  get page_name(){}
  get page_section(){}
  get page_category(){}
  get page_subcategory1(){}
  get event_category(){}
  get event_action(){}
  get event_label(){}
  get product_unit_price(){}  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do it in the constructor or a setter?  And I'm assuming you want a copy of the table not a reference to the table?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TheWizEd I want to do it in a setter yes. I want to extract the information of the table and then save it into variables with the setter.